# How to set multiple column widths in a single command in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to set the width of different columns of a table in a single query but am unable to do so.

I tried the below query but it did not work

```
column Name format a10, trn_id mail a25 ;
```

I got an error, `missing expression`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for COLUMN in SQL*Plus is, to quote from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#SQPUG034):

```
COL[UMN] [{column | expr} [option ...]]
```

There is no option to perform this on multiple columns, which means your syntax is incorrect. I can only suggest that you list each column separately.

```
column name format a10
column tm_id format a25
```

One thing to bear in mind; this is *not* a query. It is a command to format output only.