# Oracle - set multiple col format in one line

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Can I set multiple col formats in single command?

For e.g. this in a single line?

```
col HOST_NAME format a30
col VERSION format a12
col STATUS format a10
col LIMIT_VALUE format a11
```

Thanks

Comment: According to best if my knowledge, NO. It is not possible. Syntax is `COLUMN column_name FORMAT model` which do not support multiple column names.

Comment: No, but you could put them into a script, so at least then its a one-line *call*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set multiple column widths in a single command in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018652/how-to-set-multiple-column-widths-in-a-single-command-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

According to best of my knowledge, It is not possible.

Formatting must be done using following command:

```
COLUMN column_name FORMAT model
```

Here, `column_name` supports single column's name.

But yes, as suggested in the comment, you can use multiple column format in single script and call that script as a one line command.

Cheers!!